# Google charts: Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am trying to display a pie chart using chart.js however the following error appears and I'm not entirely sure why: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});                              
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

          ['Book', 'Amount'],

          <?php
            $listObject = new list($DBH); 
            $popularBooks = $listObject->getPopularBooks();
            echo "['".$popularBooks["book_name"]."', ".$popularBooks["total_amount"]."],";
           ?>

        ]);

        var options = {
         pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>

<div id="donutchart">
</div>
```

Comment: "shut your pieHole, we're working here" :)

Answer (score 1):

One of your variables is not set, either `$popularBooks["book_name"]` or `$popularBooks["total_amount"]`.

I hard coded both values into an array, and rendering works fine.
See the code segment below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});                              
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Book', 'Amount'],
  <?php
    $popularBooks = array(
      'book_name' => 'Test',
      'total_amount'  => 2
    );
    echo "['".$popularBooks["book_name"]."', ".$popularBooks["total_amount"]."],";
  ?>
]);

var options = {
 pieHole: 0.4,
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div id="donutchart">
</div>
```

Whereas omitting either value from the array declaration, results in the error you've described:

> jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 0 has 1 columns, but must have 2
>       at gvjs_Fba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:85)
>       at Object.gvjs_8m [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:86)
>       at drawChart (graph2.php:7)

Comment: I need to connect to the database in order to obtain the list of books

Comment: You'll need to revise your question to clarify on the earlier declaration of the `$DBH` variable, as I'm unsure what's set therein.

Comment: Perhaps one of the database values are missing, why don't you try looping through the array beforehand to see if each value is set for both `book_name` & `total_amount`.